# Durandal & IE: How to prevent body's scrollbar overlaying the "page-host" area and the navbar

Tags: internet-explorer, scrollbar, durandal, internet-explorer-11

Durandal 2.1 has a scrollbar problem in IE. Has anyone else seen this problem?

This only happens in IE, not Chrome or Firefox. Using IE11, I experience an intermittent problem where the vertical scrollbar for the whole body will become active and overlay the navbar and the scrollbar for the "page-host" area below the navbar. This disables mouse scrolling for the page. You can see this in the included screen shot.

[image]

I run the Durandal 2.1 Starterkit demo using WebStorm8 on a Win8.1 machine. On the Welcome page, when I grab a window edge and move it to resize the vertical space or horizontal space, I can see the vertical scrollbar flash sometimes. Then when I stop swiping the window edge and mouse over to the scrollbar, it will jump to the state shown in the screen shot. This is intermittent, and does not happen every time. But I can not build a product with this potential problem.

Anybody have any idea for a solution?

Comment: Can you stand up a demo that repros the issue?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Durandal, per se, but with the CSS that comes with the Starter Kit.  As Jonathan asks, please stand up a demo.  The Starter Kit should still perform to a certain set of expectations, even if those expectations must necessarily be limited.

Comment: @Eric: You are correct. I reproduced the problem with a Bootstrap demo program, without Durandal (http://websites.simplesphere.net/cleany/), by editing the index.html page to have just the navbar. Running this in IE11 from VS2013 will produce a stuck vertical scroll bar by doing a little mousing around to change the window size. The Durandal StarterKit opens shell.html with only the navbar, then loads the view html later. Could this set up the struck scrollbar that then interferes with the added page html? That's my guess. See the UPDATE above about my fix. Could it be a Bootstrap CSS problem?

Comment: @MartinDuo I'm not so sure it's a Bootstrap *problem*, but it may very well be a consequence of how Bootstrap works, or is styled.  We abandoned Bootstrap and the Starter Kit early on and spun up a vanilla configuration to get away from the little quirks we were dealing with.  It was more work starting from scratch with CSS, but using SMACSS helped a great deal.  Now, we have total control over every aspect of our app's styling.

Comment: @MartinDuo You might want to answer your own question (factor out your fix, and make it an answer).  Then, check the answer as the correct one.  As you may know, that's perfectly acceptable, and even encouraged, on SO.  I'm voting up your question!

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the tip about SMACSS. I had not known about that. But as a solo/retiree programmer now, I don't think I have the time to abandon Bootstrap. Gotta keep moving with the learning curve for AMD, Azure WebAPI, ReSharper9, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have solved this problem. I noticed that if I load the first html page with only the navbar, IE displays scroll bars from edge to edge even though there is there is no data below the navbar (the other browsers do not do this). So I added this css:

```
body {
     -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.page-host {
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

This prevents the interfering scroll bar, allowing the desired scroll bar to work. See my comment above for more information.